# Update a column value in a table from another table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to update the column value of old_id in table t1 with new_id column from table t2 where old_id is matching in table t2

T1

```
old_id name    desc
-----------------------
1       a       abc 
2       b       def
3       c       adf
null    d       ghi
```

T2

```
new_id old_id    code
----------------------
x        1        ab
y        2        cd
z        3        gh
```

My output should look like

T1

```
old_id name    desc
-----------------------
x       a      abc
y       b      def
z       c      adf
null    d      ghi
```

Comment: Uh, I don't see an id `3` that matches in table 2.

Comment: How do you update the row with id=3? is it a typo? If so, please edit the question, otherwise please explain the logic you need

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. Corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
update t1 set t1.old_id=(select min(t2.new_id) from t2 where t2.old_id=t1.old_id)
```

or

```
update t1 set t1.old_id=(select max(t2.new_id) from t2 where t2.old_id=t1.old_id)
```

To see the changes that will be made using this query

```
select t1.*, (select max(t2.new_id) from t2 where t2.old_id=t1=old_id) as futureIdvalue from t1
```

Comment: I got an error saying "ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Comment: That's because you have more of one value to the same old_id in t2. Retry now... the answer was modified

Comment: when we do min(t2.new_id) wont we be updating all the records with only one minimum value ?

Comment: if you have two rows in t2 with the same old_id then take the minimum NEW_ID of these two rows

Comment: If we do the update by selecting min/max value wont we be updating all the values in a column with single value?

Comment: Show the last query to see the changes

Answer (score 0):

On the beginning few assumptions:

1. I assume that there is a type in the question and third record in the T2 table has old_id = 3.
2. Because you have desc column, what is a reserved word in oracle I am treating all columns as quoted identifiers.

Here is my code (update statement at the end).

```
CREATE TABLE T1
  ( "old_id" VARCHAR2(50), 
    "name"   VARCHAR2(50), 
    "desc"   VARCHAR2(50)
  );
/
CREATE TABLE T2
  (
    "new_id" VARCHAR2(50),
    "old_id" VARCHAR2(50),
    "code"   VARCHAR2(50)
  );
/

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES('1', 'a', 'abc');
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES('2', 'b', 'def');
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES('3', 'c', 'adf');
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES(NULL, 'd', 'ghi');

INSERT INTO T2 VALUES('x', '1', 'ab');
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES('y', '2', 'cd');
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES('z', '3', 'gh');

UPDATE t1
  SET "old_id" = (SELECT "new_id"
                    FROM t2 
                   WHERE t1."old_id" = t2."old_id");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE 
 T1
 SET 
 T1.old_id= T2.new_id 
FROM 
 T1, 
 T2 
 WHERE 
 T1.old_id= T2.old_id;
```

Comment: Probably because this is neither valid standard SQL, nor is it valid for Oracle.